# how to check existence of a class instance

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I want to check the existence of a field in my Woman class. The field is a (Husband) class of its own and both Woman and Husband are entities stored in a database. The Husband class is not initialised in the constructor of the Woman class. At a later time in the program, after I manipulate some instances of the Woman class, I want to check which entries of the Woman class have still no Husband class instance (and in case initialise them). I need to do this with JpaQueries API. Basically I want to write the specification "WithNoHusband" to look through my database.

so far I have tried something like

```
(root,query,cb) -> { 
    Join<Woman, Husband> husbandJoin = root.join(husband); 
    return cb.equal(husbandJoin.isNull(), true); 
};
```

in my JpaWomanSpecificationAdapter class and

```
@Value
class WithNoHusband implements WomanSpecification {

@Override
public boolean isSatisfiedBy(Woman object) {
        return object.getHusband() == null;
}

}
```

in my WomanSpecification class without luck.

When I want to check if the Woman has any Cars, all I need to do is

```
private org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification<Woman> toJpaSpecification(WithNoCar specification) {
    (root,query,cb) -> cb.isEmpty(root.get(car)); 
}
```

and

```
@Value
class WithNoCar implements WomanSpecification {

@Override
public boolean isSatisfiedBy(Woman object) {
        return object.getCar().isEmpty();
    }
}
```

in the respective classes.

This is the basic structure of the three classes

```
 public class Woman{ 

    @Id
    Integer id;
    @Column
    String name;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "maintenanceImplementation", cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Getter
    Husband husband;
    @oneToMany(mappedBy = "maintenanceImplementation", cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Getter
    List<Car> car;
    @Column
    @Enumerated(STRING)
    @Getter
    Type typeOfWoman;

    public Woman(Integer id, String name){
        this.is=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.car = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

public class Husband {

    @Id
    Integer Id;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "WomanId", nullable = false)
    @Getter
    @Setter(PACKAGE)
    private Woman Woman;
    @Column
    String name;
}

public class Car {
    @Id
    Integer Id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "WomanId", nullable = false)
    @Getter
    @Setter(PACKAGE)
    private Woman Woman;
    @Column
    String brand;
}
```

What would I expect is that for Husband, the specification **withNoHusband** would return true to isNull condition.

of course Car has been intialised as an empty list in th constructor of Woman, so one can simply query whther that list is empty or not (without spelling out the **join clause**) but after the join clause is in place for husband, how come the result of the query **select all women without cars and without husband** is still something like

```
unexpected AST node: is near line 1, column 485 [select generatedAlias0 
from Woman as generatedAlias0, Woman as generatedAlias1 inner join
generatedAlias1.husband as generatedAlias2 where ( ( 
generatedAlias0.status=:param0 ) and ( generatedAlias0.cars is empty ) ) and 
( generatedAlias2 is null=:param1 )]
```

?

PS: I need for husband NOT to be initialised in the constructor of WOMAN since (so far) the existence of husband is based on the typeOfWoman, so if typeOfWoman is "widow", husband doesn't need to be initialised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FEI, the error I was making was to make an INNER JOIN clause (by default in Criteria API) (root,query,cb) -> { Join husbandJoin = root.join(husband, left); return cb.equal(husbandJoin.isNull(), true); }; did the trick...